# Tensorflow input pipeline using text

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

in the last weeks I tried to get the input pipeline running with tf.records under tensorflow (tf 2.0.1). From a CSV sentences are loaded and a record is generated:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import sys
import csv

PATH_PARENT = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute())
if PATH_PARENT.endswith('models'):
    PATH_PARENT = PATH_PARENT[:-len('models')]

PATH_PARENT = PATH_PARENT.replace("\\", '/')

sys.path.append(PATH_PARENT)

def create_tf_example(features, label):
    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'Sentence': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[features.encode('utf-8')])),
        'Class': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[label.encode('utf-8')])),
    }))
    return tf_example

intent_load_list = ["training_data_intent_Music_controler_0.csv"]   # Example: musik,<slot_0>,play,<slot_music_controle>

for load_intent in intent_load_list:
    start = 14
    end = load_intent.rfind("_")
    label = load_intent[start : end]
    print("loading intent " + label)
    csv_data = []

    with open(PATH_PARENT + "models/" + load_intent, 'r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            for row in csv_reader:
                clean_output = ''
                for word in row:
                    if '<' not in word:
                        clean_output = clean_output + word + ' '
                csv_data.append(clean_output)

    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(PATH_PARENT + "models/dataset.tfrecords") as writer:
        for row in csv_data:
            features = row

            example = create_tf_example(features, label)
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())        
    writer.close()
```

This works so far. This record should be loaded later, edited with a tf-hub model and then trained with the record. However, I either get an IndexEror or it fails completely:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import sys
import pathlib

PATH_PARENT = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute())
if PATH_PARENT.endswith('models'):
    PATH_PARENT = PATH_PARENT[:-len('models')]

PATH_PARENT = PATH_PARENT.replace("\\", '/')

sys.path.append(PATH_PARENT)

embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-de-dim50-with-normalization/2")

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames = [PATH_PARENT + "models/dataset.tfrecords"])

def prepare_for_training(ds, shuffle_buffer_size=1024, batch_size=2):
    ds = ds.map(lambda x: embed([x]))

    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size).batch(batch_size)

    print(ds)

    return ds


def convert_data(data):
    data_np = embed(data)
    data_list = data_np.tolist()
    return data_list


batch_size = 64
n_intents = 2

train_ds = prepare_for_training(dataset, batch_size=batch_size)

build_model = keras.Sequential()
build_model.add(keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 50)))
build_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
build_model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
build_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
build_model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
build_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_intents, activation='softmax'))

build_model.summary()
build_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

build_model.fit(train_ds, epochs=5)     # IndexError - list index out of range
print("done")
```

Has anyone perhaps tried something similar or an idea? Unfortunately the documentation didn't help much. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error in tensorflow version `2.0.1` when you don't pass the `labels` in your data. In the below example, I am writing dummy `Input` values using `TFRecordWriter` and later reading it using `TFRecordDataset` and passing it to the model.

If you run the same code in tensorflow version `2.1.0`, the error statement changes as `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.

Also, if you run the same code in tensorflow version `2.2.0`, the error statement changes as `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0'].`

**Code to reproduce the error -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
print(tf.__version__)

def write_date_tfrecord():  
    #writes 10 dummy values to replicate the issue
    Input = [20191221.123 + x for x in range(0,10)]
    print("Writing Input - ", Input)

    example = tf.train.Example(
            features = tf.train.Features(
                feature = {                    
                    'Input':tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=Input))                    
                     }
                ))


    writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter("Data.tf_record")
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

def parse_function(serialized_example):
        features = {
            'Input': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.float32,allow_missing=True) 
             }
        features = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized_example, features=features)  
        Input = features['Input']
        return Input

def dataset_generator():
    trRecordDataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("Data.tf_record")
    trRecordDataset = trRecordDataset.map(parse_function, num_parallel_calls = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return trRecordDataset

write_date_tfrecord()
generator = dataset_generator()

build_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
build_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,)))
build_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
build_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
build_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
build_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
build_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

build_model.summary()
build_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

build_model.fit(dataset_generator(), epochs=5)     # IndexError - list index out of range
print("done")
```

**Output -**

```
2.0.1
Writing Input -  [20191221.123, 20191222.123, 20191223.123, 20191224.123, 20191225.123, 20191226.123, 20191227.123, 20191228.123, 20191229.123, 20191230.123]
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 50)                100       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 20)                1020      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 20)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 63        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,183
Trainable params: 1,183
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/5
      1/Unknown - 0s 60ms/step
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d1c5c463cdc2> in <module>()
     47 build_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
     48 
---> 49 build_model.fit(dataset_generator(), epochs=5)     # IndexError - list index out of range
     50 print("done")

20 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in _model_loss(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    164 
    165         if hasattr(loss_fn, 'reduction'):
--> 166           per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(targets[i], outs[i])
    167           weighted_losses = losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
    168               per_sample_losses,

IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Solution -** I created the dummy `labels` variable and wrote the dummy `labels` using `TFRecordWriter` and later reading it using `TFRecordDataset` and passing it to the model. Now we are passing both `Input` and `labels` to the model and it works fine.

**Fixed Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
print(tf.__version__)

def write_date_tfrecord():  
    #writes 10 dummy values to replicate the issue
    Input = [20191221.123 + x for x in range(0,9)]
    labels = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]

    example = tf.train.Example(
            features = tf.train.Features(
                feature = {                    
                    'Input':tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=Input)),
                    'labels':tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=labels))                       
                     }
                ))


    writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter("Data.tf_record")
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

def parse_function(serialized_example):
        features = {
            'Input': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.float32,allow_missing=True),
            'labels': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.float32,allow_missing=True) 
             }
        features = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized_example, features=features)  
        Input = features['Input']
        labels = features['labels']
        return Input, labels

def dataset_generator():
    trRecordDataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("Data.tf_record")
    trRecordDataset = trRecordDataset.map(parse_function, num_parallel_calls = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return trRecordDataset

write_date_tfrecord()
generator = dataset_generator()

build_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
build_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,)))
build_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
build_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
build_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
build_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
build_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

build_model.summary()
build_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

build_model.fit(dataset_generator(), epochs=5)     # IndexError - list index out of range
print("done")
```

**Output -**

```
2.1.0
Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 50)                100       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)          (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 20)                1020      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_9 (Dropout)          (None, 20)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 63        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,183
Trainable params: 1,183
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 362ms/step - loss: 8705754.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 4458477.5000 - accuracy: 0.2222
Epoch 3/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 5933292.5000 - accuracy: 0.2222
Epoch 4/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 4305070.0000 - accuracy: 0.1111
Epoch 5/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 5578528.5000 - accuracy: 0.1111
done
```

Would also recommend to go through this [link](https://androidkt.com/feed-tfrecord-to-keras/) that explains "How to feed TFRecord to train Keras model".

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.